# Jenkins variable in groovy script

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, environment

I'd like to use "$WORSKPACE" variable into a groovy file called by jenkins script. But all solutions found on SO failed :

```
// KO : Wks = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('WORKSPACE')
// KO : Wks = "${WORKSPACE}"
/* KO :
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("WORKSPACE")
*/

// KO : def build = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('build')
// KO : Wks = "%WORKSPACE%"
```

Message I got :
Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject setProperty java.lang.String java.lang.Object (JenkinsHelper.name). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

**Any idea of code or option to set to allow Jenkins script to work ?**

My sample case :

File JenkinsHelper.groovy :

```
    class JenkinsHelper {
     def init(String sln) { 
      Wks = "%WORKSPACE%"
     }
    }
return new JenkinsHelper();
```

Call from jenkins script :

```
def helper = load 'C:/.../test.groovy'
helper.init("Mon SLN")
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Jenkins In-process Script Approval as a protection of possible execution of malicious scripts.

If you're an admin, register your pipeline codes in **Manage Jenkins** > **Configure System** > **Global Pipeline Libraries** to avoid this scenario.

**References:**

1. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries - Goes in details on writing a library.
2. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval

Comment: I guess you're right, this means most variables and functions are not allowed and script without admin rights have very poor capacities. I'm suprised. Shared libraries work fine, so I'll try to ask to admin to let me add my lib to be able to compile and test my program.

Answer (score 1):

You should use groovy-style environenment variable format, not a Windows-style format:

```
class JenkinsHelper {
 def init(String sln) { 
  Wks = "${WORSKPACE}"
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it the same he tried in the sacond line of the example code?

Comment: Not in the JenkinsHelper.groovy file as he provided in the question, where %WORKSPACE% used

Comment: Hi, thanks to both of you for your answers. Handras is right, I already tried your answer and it did fail for the same restriction reasons :o(   : Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject getProperty java.lang.String (JenkinsHelper.WORSKPACE). Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: If your an administrator you can approve it